# Solve the recurrence relation with no initial conditions

Tags: recurrence-relations

Solve the recurrence relation $$a_n = 6a_{n-1} − 12a_{n−2} + 8a_{n−3} + 3$$

I forgot how to these kind of questions. I remember that the condition for $n$ should be $n \ge 3$. How should I approach after? Thank you.

Comment: take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation

Comment: Using generating functions for example? Or characteristic polynomials?

Comment: Do you known (or have you known) about characteristic polynomials? You make it sound like (by using "forgot") that you could understand any of the methods mentioned by @rtybase if you saw them again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Characteristic polynomial](http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Characteristic_polynomial) (a good reference!) method will be quicker. But we need to make it homogeneous first, from
$$a_n=6a_{n-1}−12a_{n−2}+8a_{n−3}+3$$
$$a_{n+1}=6a_{n}−12a_{n−1}+8a_{n−2}+3$$
$$a_n-a_{n+1}=6a_{n-1}−12a_{n−2}+8a_{n−3}- 6a_{n}+12a_{n−1}-8a_{n−2}$$
leading to
$$a_{n+1}-7a_{n}+18a_{n−1}−20a_{n−2}+8a_{n−3}=0$$
which is homogeneous and has the following characteristic polynomial:
$$x^4-7x^3+18x^2−20x+8=0$$
$$\left(x-2\right)^3\left(x-1\right)=0$$

with the general solution
$$a_n=A\cdot(1)^n+\left(B+C\cdot n + D\cdot n^2\right)\cdot2^n=\\
A+\left(B+C\cdot n + D\cdot n^2\right)\cdot2^n$$
$A,B,C,D$ are constants, typically identified from the initial conditions, but you didn't specify any.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have a question, why is it (B+C⋅n+D⋅n^2)⋅2^n? My understanding was going to be (B+C+D) 2^n?

Comment: Have a look at the link I posted, from "If there are roots with multiplicity greater than $1$ ... " onwards.

Answer (score 1):

Using characteristic polynomials, you get $$(\lambda-2)^3=0$$ which results in $\lambda =2$ with multiplicity  $3$

Thus the homogenous solution is  $$A2^n+Bn2^n+Cn^22^n$$ and the complementary solution is $c=-3$

Adding together we get $$a_n=  A2^n+Bn2^n+Cn^22^n-3$$ where the coefficients are found by the initial values.

Answer (score 0):

It's the discrete version of the solutions to linear differential equations with constant coefficients:

- First you solve the *homogeneous* recurrence relation:
  $$a_n = 6a_{n-1} − 12a_{n−2} + 8a_{n−3}$$
- Then you find  a *particular solution* of the complete recurrence relation. As the non-homogeneous part is a constant, you can search for a constant $a_n=K$.
- Finally, add this particular solution to the general solution of the homogeneous recurrence relation.

*Solution of the homogeneous recurrence relation* :

Searching for solutions of the form $a_n=\lambda^n$ leads to the *characteristic equation* :
$$\lambda^3-6\lambda^2+12\lambda-8=(\lambda-2)^3=0.$$
This equation has a unique root `2` with multiplicity $3$, so a basis of the vector space of solutions of the homogeneous recurrence relation is
$$\bigl\{ 2^n,\, n2^n, \,n^2 2^n \bigr\}.$$