# Solve the recurrence relation $a_n = 5a_{n-1} - 6a_{n-2} + 3$ with initial conditions $a_1 = \frac{3}{2}$ and $a_2 = 3$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Solve the recurrence relation:
$$a_n = 5a_{n-1} - 6a_{n-2} + 3$$
With initial conditions $a_1 = \frac{3}{2}$ and $a_2 = 3$

I tried solving it with roots but I get a third degree polynomial with irrational roots and I'm sure that method isn't working.

Can someone help?

Comment: You should have gotten a quadratic.  What polynomial did you get?

Comment: You can try subtracting $2a_{n-1}$ from both sides to simplify.

Comment: Have a looking at some of the [examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2833001/solve-the-recurrence-relation-with-no-initial-conditions/2833018#2833018) ...

Comment: Or here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3461091

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can write down the equation to be like this:
$$a_n-5a_{n-1}+6a_{n-2}=3.$$
**First**, we solve the homogeneous equation that means:
\begin{equation}\tag 1\label 1a_n-5a_{n-1}+6a_{n-2}=0.\end{equation} Assume $a_n=\alpha^n$, then from \eqref{1} we get the characteristic equation:
$$\alpha^{n+2}-5\alpha^{n+1}-6\alpha^{n}=0.$$
Assume $\alpha^n\neq 0$, we get:
$$\alpha^2-5\alpha+6=0\iff \alpha=2$$ or $$\alpha=3,$$ hence the solution of the homogeneous equation is $$a_n=c_12^n+c_23^n$$ for some constants $c_1$ and $c_2$.

**Second**, we solve the non homogeneous equation that means:
$$a_n-5a_{n-1}+6a_{n-2}=3$$
Assume $a_n=k$, for a constant k  then we get
$$a_n-5a_{n-1}+6a_{n-2}=3\iff k-5k+6k=3\iff k=\frac{3}{2}$$
Then, the solution of non homogenous equation is:
$$a_n=\frac{3}{2}$$
Hence, the total solution is:
$$\boxed{a_n=c_13^n+c_22^n+\frac{3}{2}}$$

With initial conditions, you can find $c_1$ and $c_2$
Hope this help you!

Comment: Great answer! I have done some minor formatting modifications to your answer

Comment: Whoops Thank you